# Computing the gradient knowing directional derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose that the directional derivatives of f(x, y) are known at a given point in two nonparallel directions given by unit vectors **u** and **v**. Is it possible to find ∇f at this point?

I would like to know if the following is a valid way to solve this:

I was thinking of computing the tangent plane(assuming f is differentiable, which I believe is assumed in the problem) to the given point. Since the the tangent lines to the function in the direction of **u** and **v** must be contained in the plane, could I just take the cross product of

(u1,u2,directional derivative in the direction of **u**) x  (v1,v2,directional derivative in the direction of **v**)

and the resulting normal vector will be (a,b,c)
where

a= partial derivative with respect to x

b= partial derivative with respect to y

c = -1
Finally, the gradient would be --> (a,b)

Maybe, this is totally wrong, but I was trying to come up with a solution where the tangent plane was involved.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Just solve the linear system of equation
\begin{align}
a=\mathbf{u}\cdot \nabla f = f_x(a, b)u_x+f_y(a, b)u_y\\
b=\mathbf{v}\cdot \nabla f = f_x(a, b)v_x + f_y(a, b) u_y
\end{align}
where you know $a, b, \mathbf{u}$ and $\mathbf{v}$. That is
\begin{align}
\nabla f = [\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}]^{-1}
\begin{bmatrix}
a\\
b
\end{bmatrix}. 
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks. They had told me about this way already, but I was just wondering if there was any other alternative way, different to this one. Could you help me on that? Thank you!